# wrapAll jQuery problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to wrap three divs into one, but that group of three divs is repeating itself several times in code. Maybe my HTML will explain:

```
<div class="one" />
<div class="two" />
<div class="three" />

<div class="one" />
<div class="two" />
<div class="three" />
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one" />
  <div class="two" />
  <div class="three" />
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one" />
  <div class="two" />
  <div class="three" />
</div>
```

This is wrapping everything into one div:

```
$('.one, .two, .three').wrapAll('<div class="wrap" />')
```

How can I get the groups wrapped separately?

Comment: so each set of div.one div.two div.three needs to be wrapped in div.wrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var all = $('.one, .two, .three');
    for(i=0; i<all.length; i+=3){
        all.slice(i,i+3).wrapAll('<div class="wrap" />');
    }
});
```

See it in action: http://jsbin.com/uqosa/

By the way, `<div class="one" />` didn't work for me on Firefox, I had to close them with `</div>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('div.one').each(function() {
    var wrap = $(this).wrap('<div class="wrap"></div>').parent();
    wrap.next('div.two').appendTo(wrap);
    wrap.next('div.three').appendTo(wrap);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$(function() {
    var $ones = $('div.one');
    var $twos = $('div.two');
    var $threes = $('div.three');

    $ones.each(function(idx) {
        $('<div class="wrap"></div>')
            .append($ones.eq(idx))
            .append($twos.eq(idx))
            .append($threes.eq(idx))
            .appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my head this *should* work:

```
$('.one').each(function() {
    var wrap = $('<div>').addClass('wrap'), two = $(this).next(), three = $(two).next();
    $(this).after(wrap).appendTo(wrap)
    two.appendTo(wrap), three.appendTo(wrap)
});
```

Comment: Updated my answer a few times.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.matchUntil = function(expr) {
    var match = [];
    this.each(function(){
        match = [this];
        for ( var i = this.nextSibling; i; i = i.nextSibling ) {
            if ( i.nodeType != 1 ) { continue; }
            if ( $(i).filter(expr).length > 0 ) { break; }
            match.push( i );
        }
    });
    return this.pushStack( match );
};
```

usage:

```
$(".one").each( function() {
    $(this).matchUntil(".one").wrapAll("<div class='wr'></div>");
})
```

it's just modified version of http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_1.2_Roadmap#.nextUntil.28.29_.2F_.prevUntil.28.29, which doesn't seem to work with new jQuery.