# jQuery: wrapAll but separate sets of elements?

Tags: jquery, wrapall

I have a somewhat grouping system which all the elements between two divs are grouped together. See the code below to see what I'm trying to say:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var groupo = $('div').filter(function(){return $(this).text().match(/\[group\]/)}); //finds "[group]"
var groupc = $('div').filter(function(){return $(this).text().match(/\[\/group\]/)}); //finds "[/group]"
groupc.addClass("groupclose"); //adds the class groupclose so that it can be used by nextUntil
 groupo.nextUntil(".groupclose").wrapAll('<div class="group"></div>');
 groupo.remove();
 groupc.remove();
});
```

When the HTML is:

```
<div>[group]</div>
<div>first</div>
<div>second</div>
<div>[/group]</div>
```

it works just fine, but when there are two or more 'groups' the wrapAll wraps them together, for example:

```
<div>[group]</div>
<div>first</div>
<div>second</div>
<div>[/group]</div>

<div>[group]</div>
<div>this is in</div>
<div>another group</div>
<div>which get wrapped together with the one above</div>
<div>[/group]</div>
```

The problem is similar to this [wrapAll jQuery problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527944/wrapall-jquery-problem) but in that case we know the number of divs in a set, while in this case we don't.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: added the link to jsbin http://jsbin.com/ejepu3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just needed to loop through the contents of `groupo`. Also, no need to use `filter()`. You can use the `:contains('')` selector

```
var groupo = $("div:contains('[group]')");
var groupc = $("div:contains('[/group]')").addClass("groupclose");

$(groupo).each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(".groupclose").wrapAll('<div class="group"></div>');
});

groupo.remove();
groupc.remove();
```

working version: http://jsfiddle.net/48Pfp/2/